# VueJs Nested props coming through undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to access an array which is part of a prop (event) passed into a component, but when in created() or mounted() the array part of the event prop (the rest is fine) comes through as undefined.

As can be seen below, when I inspect the props in the vue chrome plugin, the registration_fields are there.

I can add a watcher to the event prop and can access the registration_fields that way, but this seems very awkward to have to do this to access already passed in data.

This is from the Chrome vue inspector:

```
event:Object
  address1_field:"Some Address 1"
  address2_field:"Some Address 2"
  approved:true
  registration_fields:Array[1]
```

This is what part of my vue file looks like:

```
  export default {

    props: ['event'],

    data() {
     return {
       regFields: []
     }
    },

    created() {
      this.regFields = this.event.registration_fields // Undefined here!
    },

    watch: {
      event() {
        this.regFields = this.event.registration_fields //Can access it here
        });
      }
    }
 }
```

I am using Vue 2.4.4

This is how the component is called:

```
<template>
    <tickets v-if="event" :event="event"></tickets>
</template>

<script>

  import tickets from './main_booking/tickets.vue'

  export default {
    created() {
      var self = this;
      this.$http.get('events/123').then(response => {
        self.event = response.data
      }).catch(e => {
        alert('Error here!');
      })
    },
    data: function () {
      return {event: {}}
    },

    components: {
      tickets: tickets
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: It is a problem in the vue dev tools, btw why you assign the prop to local data variable. You can use directly event passed from the prop

Comment: How are you passing the prop to this component?

Comment: Is `event` is async loading (from ajax, ...)?

Comment: I am just using the assignment as an example. I need to do a count of the registration_fields as soon as the props load.

Comment: Event is loading from ajax, but I wrap this component in a v-if="event", and other attributes on the event come through, just not the ones in an array.

Answer (score 2):

It actually works fine without the watcher.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    event: undefined
  },
  components: {
    subC: {
      props: ['event'],

      data() {
        return {
          regFields: []
        }
      },

      created() {
        this.regFields = this.event.registration_fields // Undefined here!
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.event = {
        registration_fields: [1, 3]
      };
    }, 800);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sub-c v-if="event" :event="event" inline-template>
    <div>
      {{regFields}}
    </div>
  </sub-c>
</div>
```

If, as Belmin Bedak suggests in the comment below, `event` is populated asynchronously, it comes in as undefined because it's undefined. In that case, you need a watcher, or, somewhat more elegantly, use a computed:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    event: {}
  },
  components: {
    subC: {
      props: ['event'],
      computed: {
        regFields() {
          return this.event.registration_fields;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // delay proper population
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => { this.event = {registration_fields: [1,2,3]}; }, 800);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sub-c :event="event" inline-template>
    <div>
      {{regFields}}
    </div>
  </sub-c>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because `event`, in his case, is sort of async operation.

Comment: Good suggestion. Updated answer.

Comment: The use of computed is a good idea. For the async operation, I do load the event data async from the server. But I wrap the component in a v-if="event", so I would have thought the whole component wouldn't load until the event is loaded, unless I am mistaken. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I've updated my first snippet to have a `v-if` and delayed populating of `event`. How is your `event` initialized?

Comment: Hi @RoyJ Like this:
<template>
 <tickets v-if="event" :event="event"></tickets>
</template>
<script>
  import tickets from './main_booking/tickets.vue'
  export default {
    created() {
      var self = this;
      this.$http.get('bookings/+ id)
        .then(response => {
          self.event = response.data
        })
        .catch(e => {
        })
    },

    data: function () {
      return {
        event: {}
      }
    },
    components: {
      tickets: tickets
    }
  }
</script>

Comment: Note that you initialize `event` to an empty object, which is a truthy value, so `v-if` will render. If `event` starts out `null`, it would not render.